# Mac can't get through the vmware hosts on Windows

Tags: mac, vmware-workstation

I have a windows server with VMWare set up as below:

Windows: 192.168.2.16
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:192.168.211.1
Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:192.168.112.1

VMWare: host1

ens37: 192.168.211.251
virbr0: 192.168.122.1

Mac:
192.168.2.17

I can ping from Windows to Mac;
I can ping from VMware host1 to Mac;
I cannot ping from Mac to Windows;
I cannot ping from Mac to host1;

I need to be able to reach host1 from Mac, but I believe the blockage from Mac to Windows is preventing Mac to reach host1.

Can anyone help sort it out?

I can provide further information if needed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: "I cannot ping from Mac to Windows"-- its the windows firewall holding u there

Answer (score 1):

By default, In your windows ICMP incoming requests are blocked. You can enable ICMP by

Open a command prompt "Run as administrator" and run this

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

or

1. open Windows Firewall
2. Click Advanced Settings on the left
3. left pane of the resulting window, click Inbound Rules
4. In the right pane, find the rules titled File and Printer Sharing
   (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)
5. Right-click each rule and choose Enable Rule.

Like wise you have to enable ICMP in your other host `(host1)` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, following your suggestion enables Mac to Windows, however still cannot reach VMWare.

Comment: host1 what is the os?

Comment: u have to open linux firewall for icmp as well